# Reverting a sorted array back to its original order

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, uicollectionview

I am working on sorting arrays of data within a Collection View. There are 3 ways I would like to sort the data: alphabetically, numerically, and no sort at all (no sort at all should sort the order of the data how it's set up in the model.) The sorting happens via 3 different UIButtons.

In my code below, allAnimalsArray is the full array of data that gets displayed in the Collection View.

```
// Animal Name button pressed
let sortAZ = allAnimalsArray.sorted(by: { $0.animalName < $1.animalName })
allAnimalsArray = sortAZ
allAnimalsCollectionView.reloadData()

// Animal Weight button pressed
let sortByWeight = allAnimalsArray.sorted(by: { $0.pounds < $1.pounds })
allAnimalsArray = sortByWeight
allAnimalsCollectionView.reloadData()

// NO SORT button pressed
let noSorting = allAnimalsArray
allAnimalsArray = noSorting
allAnimalsCollectionView.reloadData()
```

**My problem is the NO SORT method doesn't change the sort.** It keeps the same order as whichever was pressed before it.

It was my understanding .sorted makes a *copy* of the data so the original data is retained (whereas .sort modifies the original data).

**How do I change the NO SORT method above to simply display the data without any sorting? (meaning it's displayed *exactly* how the data is set up in the model)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to

1. either save a copy of the entire unsorted array and use when you need to revert
2. or at least save the indices of that array so you can use them to impose the
   original unsorted state

Answer (score 1):

If the original array has no sortable order, then I suggest you never modify the original array. Keep a second array that is based on the current sort and use this second array as the basis of the collection view's data model.

When the user chooses a different sort method, you simply update the second array from the original, unmodified array, and then reload the collection view.

```
let allAnimalsArray = ... // the original array that you never modify
var sortedArray = [YourAnimalClass]()
```

All of your data source methods are based on `sortedArray`.

If the user chooses "no sort" then you do:

```
sortedArray = allAnimalsArray
allAnimalsCollectionView.reloadData()
```

If the user chooses one of the sorts then you do:

```
sortedArray.allAnimalsArray.sorted(by: { $0.whatever < $1.whatever })
allAnimalsCollectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: This was helpful. But rather than changing all of my data source methods, I just made a copy of the unsorted array. Then in the No Sort button method, I use allAnimalsArray = originalSort.

Comment: That's still the same solution. All you did is use different variable names. And don't forget you can upvote helpful answers.